# Providing a Custom `RouteReuseStrategy` From Inside a Lazy Loaded Module Does Not Work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular9

I want to provide my own [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) only for one of my lazy loaded modules. Thus I've registered my own `CustomReuseStrategy` class like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'items',
        component: ItemsComponent,
        children: [{ path: ':id', component: ItemComponent }],
      },
    ]),
  declarations: [ItemsComponent, ItemComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy }],
})
export class MyLazyLoadedModule {}
```

But upon route navigation none of the [methods](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy#methods) is invoked. It seems as if Angular doesn't even recognize, that I've registered this provider.

Comment: Been working on the same problem for a couple days. Seems you can only registers a reuse strategy on the root routing module -- but then reattachment becomes problematic. Were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Nope. This feature had not enough priority for me to continue working on it. But I would appreciate if you'd post a solution if you find one :)

Comment: I did a bunch of reading on the Angular git support forum. It seems there's no idempotent to reattach the child route because the parent reinstantiates on every router event, and it may not be in the state it was at the time of detachment. RouteReuseStrategy and lazy loading modules are mutually incompatible at this time.